# EmberJS file upload via jquery-file-upload

Tags: ember.js, jquery-file-upload

I have an Ember.js controller and I'm attempting to send a file to my rails controller with jquery file upload.

I started with this:

```
myControllerAction: ->
  $('#fileupload').fileupload(
    url: "/api/v1/comics"
    dataType: 'json'
    formData:
      comic: {
        title: self.get('comicTitle')
        prompt_one_id: self.get('prompts')[0].get('id')
        prompt_two_id: self.get('prompts')[1].get('id')
      }
    )
```

Which did work, but it sent the form as soon as a file was selected. I want to do it all when the user submits the form. So I tried this:

```
  didInsertElement: ->
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
      url: "/api/v1/comics"
      dataType: 'json'
      formData:
        comic: {
          title: self.get('comicTitle')
          prompt_one_id: self.get('prompts')[0].get('id')
          prompt_two_id: self.get('prompts')[1].get('id')
        }
      add: (e, data) ->
        data.submit()
      progressall: (e, data) ->
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        $('#progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%')
    )

   myControllerAction: ->
    self = @
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('add')
```

However that doesn't work. It throws a javascript error:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'add'
```

I thought setting everything up on element insertion would be initializing the object. So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: To add template

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputTitle">Title</label>
        <div class="controls">
          {{input type="text" valueBinding="comicTitle"}}
          {{input type="file" id="fileupload" valueBinding="comicFile"}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <button {{action myControllerAction}} id="upload_comic" class="btn btn-inverse">Upload Comic</button>
      <div id="progress">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the template?

Comment: what seems to be the problem for you is what i actually trying to acheive.. here is my problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699686/emberjs-file-upload-via-jquery-file-upload

Can you help to fix the jquery upload with ember? I just cant make the jquery file upload to work with ember.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the cause of the error, but try to do it with the [afterRender](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1528) callback. Also use `this.$('#fileupload')` instead of `$('#fileupload')`. Code:

```
  didInsertElement: ->
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'setupFileUpload')

  setupFileUpload: ->
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
      url: "/api/v1/comics"
      dataType: 'json'
      formData:
        comic: {
          title: self.get('comicTitle')
          prompt_one_id: self.get('prompts')[0].get('id')
          prompt_two_id: self.get('prompts')[1].get('id')
        }
      add: (e, data) ->
        data.submit()
      progressall: (e, data) ->
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        $('#progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%')
    )
```

Comment: Any idea how one would cleanly send it with a context? like url: "/api/v1/users/:ID". Useful for updating a user or resource's file